# Add camera shake to a camera with track to mod

Tags: camera, constraints, photorealism

How can I add camera shake to a camera that has a track to constraint to a moving object?

Answer (score 3):

Create an empty, set it child of the moving object, set the camera track to constraint to the empty, then add some noise to the Z loc of the empty.

To do this set a starting loc keyframe, then in the graph editor select the Z loc channel of the empty and add a graph noise modifier.

[image]

Comment: this is the right answer, but if he is a beginner - he has no chance to do it.

Comment: yes maybe explain how to add noise

Comment: I thought the problem he encountered was only that giving noise to a track to constrained camera isn't effective because the constraint levels away the shaking. Anyway I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’m pretty good with blender and can do this.